# What does [i,:] mean in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression

So I'm finished one part of this assignment I have to do. There's only one part of the assignment that doesn't make any sense to me.

I'm doing a LinearRegression model and according to others I need to apply `ans[i,:] = y_poly` at the very end, but I never got an answer as to why.

Can someone please explain to me what `[i,:]` means? I haven't found any explanations online.

Comment: numpy slicing notation. I haven't found a good duplicate. If anyone finds one, I have added the "python" tag so you can dupehammer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's specific to the `numpy` module, used in most data science modules.

```
ans[i,:] = y_poly
```

this is assigning a vector to a slice of numpy 2D array (slice assignment). Self-contained example:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([[0,0,0],[1,1,1]])
>>> a[0,:] = [3,4,5]
>>> a
array([[3, 4, 5],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

There is also slice assignment in base python, using only one dimension (`a[:] = [1,2,3]`)

Comment: Okay thanks, the does help, I do have a for loop that says: for i, degree in enumerate([1,3,6,9]). So I understand what the 2D slicing is for.

Comment: Though i also realized I can get the same answers without the comma (ans[i:]).

Comment: `a[0,:]` is different from `a[0:]`. The second one copies the vector in all rows.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are also using `numpy` to manipulate data (as a matrix)?

If based on `numpy`,  `ans[i,:]` means to pick the `ith` 'row' of `ans` with all of its 'columns'.
Note: when dealing with `numpy` arrays, we should (almost) always use `[i, j]` instead of `[i][j]`. This might be counter-intuitive if you've used Python or Java to manipulate matrixes before.

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case [] means the indexing operator for a class object which can be used by defining the **getitem** method

```
class A:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        pass
```

key can be literally anything. In your case "[1,:]" key is a tuple containing of "1" and a slice(None, None, None). Such a key can be useful if your class represents multi-dimensional data which you want to access via [] operator. A suggested by others answers this could be a numpy array:

Here is a quick example of how such a multi-dimensional indexing could work:

```
class A:
    values = [[1,2,3,4], [4,5,6,7]]
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        i, j = key
        if isinstance(i, int):
            i = slice(i, i + 1)
        if isinstance(j, int):
            j = slice(j, j + 1)
        for row in self.values[i]:
            print(row[j])

>>>a = A()
>>>a[:,2:4]
[3, 4]
[6, 7]
>>>a[1,1]
[5]
>>>a[:, 2]
[3]
[6]
```